# why is my fastapi or uvicorn getting shutdown?

Tags: python, fastapi, multilabel-classification, uvicorn, simpletransformers

I am trying to run a service that uses simple transformers Roberta model to do classification. the inferencing script/function itself is working as expected when tested. when i include that with fast api its shutting down the server.

```
uvicorn==0.11.8
fastapi==0.61.1
simpletransformers==0.51.6
cmd : uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 src.main:app
```

---

```
@app.get("/article_classify")
def classification(text:str):
    """function to classify article using a deep learning model.
    Returns:
        [type]: [description]
    """

    _,_,result = inference(text)
    return result
```

error :

```
INFO:     Started server process [8262]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:36454 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:36454 - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
INFO:     127.0.0.1:36454 - "GET /docs HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:36454 - "GET /openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
before
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 17.85it/s]
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Finished server process [8262]
```

inferencing script :

```
model_name = "checkpoint-3380-epoch-20"
model = MultiLabelClassificationModel("roberta","src/outputs/"+model_name)
def inference(input_text,model_name="checkpoint-3380-epoch-20"):
    """Function to run inverence on one sample text"""
    #model = MultiLabelClassificationModel("roberta","src/outputs/"+model_name)
    all_tags =[]
    if isinstance(input_text,str):
        print("before")
        result ,output = model.predict([input_text])
        print(result)
        tags=[]
        for idx,each in enumerate(result[0]):
            if each==1:
                tags.append(classes[idx])
        all_tags.append(tags)
    elif isinstance(input_text,list):
        result ,output = model.predict(input_text)
        tags=[]
        for res in result : 
            for idx,each in enumerate(res):
                if each==1:
                    tags.append(classes[idx])
            all_tags.append(tags)

    return result,output,all_tags
```

update: tried with flask and the service is working but when adding uvicorn on top of flask its getting stuck in a loop of restart.

Comment: It looks like it stops exactly at (or right after)  processing the line `result ,output = model.predict([input_text])`. You could try debugging from there, putting the line of code within a `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by starting a process pool using multiprocessing explicitly.

```
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
try:
    set_start_method('spawn')
except RuntimeError:
    pass
@app.get("/article_classify")
def classification(text:str):
    """function to classify article using a deep learning model.
    Returns:
        [type]: [description]
    """
    manager = Manager()

    return_result = manager.dict()
    # as the inference is failing 
    p = Process(target = inference,args=(text,return_result,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    # print(return_result)
    result = return_result['all_tags']
    return result
```

Comment: great find. Tried every combination with other processes running in the same instance. Tested also with set_start_method('fork') but set_start_method('spawn') did the trick and seems stable now. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Although the accepted solution works, I would like to suggest a less hacky solution that uses `uvicorn` workers instead.

You may want to try adding `--workers 4` to your `CMD` so that it reads:

```bash
uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 --workers 4 src.main:app
```

Comment: thanks. It worked truly, though I'm running uvicorn in my main method. So it can be replaced to `uvicorn.run("src.main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5050, workers=4)`. but I wonder why this solution works.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/issues/761 it's related to multiprocessing.

I set args={'use_multiprocessing': False} and the web server isn't shutting down any longer.

Comment: And at the end there someone says you also need `"use_multiprocessing_for_evaluation":False` which was necessary for me to work with FastAPI.

Answer (score 1):

I hit into similar problem recently. My situation might be a bit different but want to provide it as a reference. I was using sentence-transformer that requires downloading large weight file, the download process takes o(10) seconds. However, the default unicorn has a setting `timeout_notify=30`. By reading the source code, it seems to be the reason that causes the server keeps restarting, as the download takes a long time (close to 30 seconds).

Later on, I use a different way to speed up the download then the restarting issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently come across this exact issue, and solved it in a different way. Maybe this is useful to someone.

For me, the problem was that the VM I was running my FastAPI App on was simply  **out of disk space**. My app deals with rather large video files, which caused it to crash while trying to write the `UploadFile`s to the hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

put the entire function under a `try-except` block and show the output so we can investigate the real issue.

```py
import logging

@app.get("/article_classify")
def classification(text:str):
    """function to classify article using a deep learning model.
    Returns:
        [type]: [description]
    """
    try:
    _,_,result = inference(text)
    except:
        logging.exception("something bad happened")  # automatically print exception info

    return result
```

Comment: there is no error/exception that is coming up, that was the issue to start of with.